# Shell find logic into Python script

Tags: python, bash, shell, sh

```bash
cd db/test/vs
ls
find . -name '*.vrlp' | while read FILENAME
do
    TEST_CASE=`echo $FILENAME | sed s/"\.\/"//g | sed s/"\.vrlp"//g | rev | cut -f1 -d"/" | rev`
    CLASS=`echo $FILENAME | sed s/"\.\/"//g | sed s/"\/$TEST_CASE"//g | sed s/"\.vrlp"//g`
done
```

There are a lot of class files (FILENAME) as vrlp inside the vs folder, for example:

Currently, if I am running the bash command, it returns all files with .vrlp for me.

```
a.vrlp
a.ce.template.a.vrlp
abcd.vrlp
abcd.ce.template.a.vrlp
dfe.vrlp
dfe.ce.template.a.vrlp
gdfd.vrlp
gdfd.ce.template.a.vrlp
test001.vrlp
test001.ce.template.a.vrlp
hies.ce.template.a.vrlp
hies.vrlp
....
```

But what I want is something like this:

```
a.vrlp
abcd.vrlp
dfe.vrlp
gdfd.vrlp
test001.vrlp
hies.vrlp
```

without any `.ce.template.a` or any other patterns. How can I filter this in Python?

And also I don't know how to convert sed shell command logic into Python. For example, what is the following command in bash doing?

```bash
    TEST_CASE=`echo $FILENAME | sed s/"\.\/"//g | sed s/"\.vrlp"//g | rev | cut -f1 -d"/" | rev`
    CLASS=`echo $FILENAME | sed s/"\.\/"//g | sed s/"\/$TEST_CASE"//g | sed s/"\.vrlp"//g`
```

Comment: The files you see are only the output of the `ls` command. The two last commands assign to two variables `TEST_CASE` and `CLASS`, respectively but nothing is done with them. They basically contain the file names with paths and extensions stripped away.

Comment: sed's `s` command substitutes a regular expression. Roughly said, you can convert `sed s/foo/bar/g` into python's `re.sub(foo, bar, string)`. However, there are better tools in python (and in bash) to get a file's name, e.g. `os.path.basename()`.

Comment: Please restrict one posting to a single question. Use several posts to ask for more than one question. Also there is no Python code shown in your question, and I don't understand why it is tagged as _bash_ **and** _sh_.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This might work:

```py
import os

for _, _, files in os.walk('./'):
    for file in files:
        basename = os.path.basename(file)
        # print the file name if it does not contain a dot - adjust to your needs.
        if not '.' in os.path.splitext(basename)[0]:
            print(basename)
```

If run on a directory with files

```
foo.vrlp
foo.ce.template.a.vrlp
```

It will print only

```
foo.vrlp
```